# How can I make a RadioButton with overlapping text?

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm adding programmatically multiple answers to a questions as RadioButtons in a RadioGroup (see code and image below).

I almost achieved it but instead of having a radio button with a text on its side (see image below), I would like to have only the text and the background.

Can I get rid of the radio button?

Or can I set my current background as the radio button (with checked/unchecked states), and add a text overlapping it?

```
RadioGroup answer_container = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer_container);

while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {

    RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(PCItem.this);
    answer.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ANS_TEXT)));
    answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_ans);
    answer.setPadding((int)(30 * density), 0, 0, 0);
    answer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(775 * density), (int)(81 * density));
    params.setMargins(0, (int)(20*density), 0, 0);
    answer.setLayoutParams(params);

    answer_container.addView(answer);

    c.moveToNext();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Even i am finding the same issue can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it using

```
answer.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
```

to remove the button, and using a selector as btn_ans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_choix_unsel" /> 
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_choix_sel" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `radioButton.setButtonDrawable()`. You can also specify different drawables for each button state (including `checked`/`unchecked`) using a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

To completely remove the button you can simply set it as `null`:

```
<RadioButton 
    android:button="@null"
    ...
/>
```

Be aware that by code `radioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);` doesn't work! The correct way is to set an empty `StateListDrawable`:

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
```

If you have more items, you can create a custom style to override the default properties of `RadioButton`:

```
<style name="CustomRadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
   <item name="android:button">@null</item>
   <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This will set the radio button. I want to remove it, or make the text overlapping it.

Comment: I tried to set the button to null programmatically (`answer.setButtonDrawable(null)`), but it still shows up...