# How can I programmatically set android:button="@null"?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I'm trying to programmatically add a set of RadioButtons to a RadioGroup like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RANGE; i++) {
    RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
    button.setId(i);
    button.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    button.setChecked(i == currentHours); // Select button with same index as currently selected number of hours
    button.setButtonDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((RadioGroup)view.getParent()).check(view.getId());
            currentHours = view.getId();
        }
    });

    radioGroupChild.addView(button);
}
```

and I need to set the button drawable to null (I want just text on top of my background). Manually doing this in the XML with `android:button="@null"` works great, but I don't want to hardcode each radio button. I've tried just doing `button.setButtonDrawable(null)` but it doesn't change anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a better answer in case you might actually want to use a background selector http://stackoverflow.com/a/8910925/317889

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do this:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

If your drawable has a reference to selector you can make it transparent through your selector xml:

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

as you'd probably found the solution ;)

Comment: I said above, I've tried this and it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: It's setBackgroundDrawable, not setButtonDrawable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that. The problem is, that just removes the background, which where I'm setting my custom selector drawable.

Comment: Ok, then you should set a transparent color in your selector xml.

Comment: Awesome, it worked with my selector with just this item: `<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />`. If you add that to your answer, I'll mark it! Thanks!

Comment: As of API 16, `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated. Use `setBackground(null)` instead in this case.

Answer (score 47):

You need to set an empty `StateListDrawable` as the drawable. So the Java equivalent of `android:button="@null"` is:

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Not sure why it is not the best answer.

Comment: this is same as 
setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);

Comment: Not on all devices, why?
did not work on hTC one X, and worked on Nexus 4.

Comment: This worked better than the answer that is set as the answer! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

`setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent))` 
should do the trick.

Only this worked for me.

Comment: You can simply put `setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);` as @amalan pointed out in a previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me in multiple devices and APIs and is as simple as it gets was `setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin you can do that

```
radioButton.buttonDrawable = null
```